# How to add a data relation as a data source

Tags: c#, exception, data-binding, relationship

I have filled a data set with many tables and added relations to the tables. I am now trying to bind a master and child grid views to display the information. However I get the following exception when I try to add the relation as a data source:-
DataMember property 'FK_PREWODOC_PREWORKS' cannot be found on the DataSource.

the code I am using is

```
 woViewDs = _WoUtility.GetDataset;
 var prewodocbs = new BindingSource(woViewDs, prewodoc.ViewTable);
 var preworksbs = new BindingSource(woViewDs, "FK_PREWODOC_PREWORKS");
```

At runtime the code throws the exception when tring to create the binding source preworksbs. Thw data set woViewDs has data in both tables and I can see a relation called FK_PREWODOC_PREWORKS in the relation list.What am I Missing?

Answer (score 0):

The binding source is incorrect on preworksbs it should be as below

```
var preworksbs = new BindingSource(prewodocbs , "FK_PREWODOC_PREWORKS");
```